# How can research items be transported?

Tags: astroneer

Is there any way you can move them with the **truck** or the **rover**, for example? I know you can add **storage units** to those but that only lets you place materials and I couldn't find anything on the [wiki](http://astroneer.gamepedia.com/Astroneer_Wiki) about moving **research items**

Comment: I have not tried this because i dont have a buddy to test with right now, but could one person ride, standing, on the back of a vehicle while holding the item normally, and have the other person drive them to the research station?

Comment: @Dpeif that would be a fun way of doing it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I got home I tried this and you can actually **transport them using the rover**(haven't tried with the truck yet but I guess it's the same). In order to do so, you need to have two empty plugs on it where you then are going to **place the research items just the same way you'd place any material**.

You can also see how to do it here:

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of slots - There are single points, and there are paired points. The storage unit from the Printer mounts to 2 paired points, but only provides 8 single points, so only holds resources and small items.

There is also a schematic for a Vehicle Storage unit that can be built onto a truck or rover from the Vehicle Bay that converts two pairs of paired slots into 4 pairs of paired slots.

[image]

You can mount 4 research items on this storage unit. You can also add the Printer crafted storage units to these pairs of slots to carry up to 32 resources, or mix and match as needed.

Important note - If you build this storage unit onto a Rover, there won't be room for a driver's seat, so it can only be towed by another vehicle. Similarly, you can build two of these storage units onto a truck frame.